# Send stream from hdhomerun to AWS EC2 instance

Tags: ffmpeg, wowza

I'm trying something odd to get fun. Send stream from [hdhomerun](https://www.silicondust.com/product/hdhomerun-quatro-eu/) to AWS EC2 instance.

First aproach. Read stream with ffmpeg
(tested locally successfully)

hdhomerun_config discover sya my device have ip 192.168.1.200 so I open port on my router in this way

```
<my home public ip>:5005 -> 192.168.1.200:80
<my home public ip>:5004 -> 192.168.1.200:5004
```

w3m and telnet say everything is ok.

But...

from EC2 instance I do

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -i 'http://<my home public ip>:5004/auto/v5057?transcode=internet240' -t 12 -vn -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 16000 -ac 1 '/tmp/test.wav'
```

In tuner1 I can see...

```
Virtual Channel none
Frequency   698.000 MHz
Program Number  186
Modulation Lock t8qam64
Signal Strength 89%
Signal Quality  100%
Symbol Quality  100%
Streaming Rate  none
Resource Lock   <EC2 public ip>
```

In hdhomerun system logs...

```
19700102-10:27:25 Tuner: tuner0 tuning 5057 Telecinco (t8qam64:698MHz-186)
19700102-10:27:25 Tuner: tuner0 streaming http to <EC2 public ip>:34124
```

Everything seems ok but ffmpeg don't get any data.

Seccond aproach. Send stream to wowza

I have a wowza server running in EC2 instance

From a linux box at my home I do.

```
root# /usr/bin/hdhomerun_config 1250D7B2 scan /tuner1 scan.log
root# /usr/bin/hdhomerun_config 1250D7B2 set /tuner1/channel auto:651000000
root# /usr/bin/hdhomerun_config 1250D7B2 get /tuner1/streaminfo
root# /usr/bin/hdhomerun_config 1250D7B2 get /tuner1/program 190
root# /usr/bin/hdhomerun_config 1250D7B2 set /tuner1/target rtp://<wowza server public ip>:1935/TEST/hdhr
root# echo $?
root# 0
```

Ends without error buy doesn't work
This was a long shot but ....

Any ideas to do this.

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I use ffmpeg as encoder in this way...

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i http://192.168.1.50:5004/auto/v5055?transcode=internet240 -vn -ar 16000 -ac 1 -f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp -muxdelay 0.1 rtsp://22.22.22.22/XXX/STREAM
```

To daemonize I did this...

```
[Unit]
Description=XXX ffserver incoming stream

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i "http://192.168.1.50:5004/auto/v5055?transcode=internet240" -vn -ar 16000 -ac 1 -f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp -muxdelay 0.1 rtsp://22.22.22.22/XXX/STREAM
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 1):

The HDHomerun tuners send the stream with a ttl=3 so it'll never make it to your EC2 instance once it leaves the router. My solution for streaming across the internet was to use an nginx reverse proxy at the HDHomerun location to forward 5004 to the tuner.

Comment: Good solution graphic maker, but I found another one. Please, read below.

Comment: Any chance you would share your nginx config?